# How can I get the currently playing Song from a Browser in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, background-music, obsidian

I want to make a Plugin for Obsidian.md where I see what Track is currently Playing and, if possible, want to be able to pause/play/skip the tracks. In Wallpaper Engine the displaying works but there I just use the Inbuilt functions. How can i do this in NodeJS so it even works with YouTube Music? It is okay if it only works on Windows

I tried the MediaSession API (`const mediaMetadata = navigator.mediaSession.metadata.title;`) but I dont get an output besides NULL. And on google I sadly didnt find anything usable.

Sincerely
Speedy